# Получение даты и оператор if

Tags: java, android

Помогите с получением даты Андроид устройства. Есть вот этот код, я хочу чтоб после получении даты он грузил определённый .xml файл(разметка). Знаю что надо использовать оператор if, как правильно его приделать сюда? Android Studio

```
private String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

Comment: что за xml, разметка? Попробуйте сформулировать свой вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен людям, которые ничего не знают о вашей проблеме, без помощи экстрасенсов

Comment: Да,в Android Studio,так как это можно сделать?

Comment: @GeorgeBotnar вопрос задан неясно. пеформулируйте иначе вас **заслуженно** заминусуют

Comment: Из вашего вопроса совершенно непонятно, в чем именно ваша проблема и что вы хотите получить в итоге. Вам не понятен синтаксис оператора if? Вы не можете составить условие? Проблема все же с оператором if или с получением даты? и какой даты? или что .. Это не форум экстрасенсов, чтобы догадываться о ваших затруднениях, оформите вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен людям, которые не имеют никакого представления о том , что у вас не получается.

Comment: У меня есть xml файл(разметка),Мне нужно получить дату с устройства,чтоб загрузить этот xml.

Comment: @pavlofff У меня есть xml файл(разметка),Мне нужно получить дату с Андроид устройства,чтоб загрузить этот xml.

Comment: причем здесь if ? сколько можно из вас выпытывать .. нажмите кнопку "править" под вопросом и изложите вашу проблему так, чтобы не пришлось ничего спрашвать дополнительно или решайте ее сами тогда, абсолютно не понятно, что и зачем вам надо

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно крутиться от даты **именно** в текстовом формате, то можно так:

```
if (getDate().equals("01.01.2017 06:00")) {
    // some actions
}
```

Как вариант, можно использовать представление даты в миллисекундах:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");

String currentDateString = getDate();
long currentDateInMills = simpleDateFormat.parse(currentDateString).getTime();

String someDateString = "01.01.2017 06:00";
long someDateInMills = simpleDateFormat.parse(someDateString).getTime();

if (currentDateInMills == someDateInMills) {
    // some actions
}
```

Comment: Сейчас я имею это,но приложение запущенное на смартфоне вылетает.https://pastebin.com/7dwwjhdc

Comment: @GeorgeBotnar, Покажите стек-трейс.